# use checkbox within iterator in strut 2.0

Tags: java, struts2, iterator

In my sample application this worked perfect

```
<s:iterator value="menuGroup" var="menu">
                <s:textfield value="%{#menu.name}"></s:textfield>
            </s:iterator>
```

but when i use checkbox instead i.e `

```
<s:iterator value="menuGroup" var="menuLst">
                <s:checkbox value="%{menuLst.name}"></s:checkbox>
            </s:iterator>
```

it gives an error like

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression parameters.name is undefined on line 23, column 56 in template/xhtml/checkbox.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:124)
    at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName._getAsTemplateModel(DynamicKeyName.java:85)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.ExistsExpression._getAsTemplateModel(ExistsExpression.java:71)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.isTrue(Expression.java:138)
    at freemarker.core.AndExpression.isTrue(AndExpression.java:68)
    at freemarker.core.BooleanExpression._getAsTemplateModel(BooleanExpression.java:61)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:90)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:208)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:208)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:188)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:559)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:513)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.pages.system.acl_002dgroup_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fcheckbox_005f0(acl_002dgroup_jsp.java:440)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.pages.system.acl_002dgroup_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fiterator_005f0(acl_002dgroup_jsp.java:411)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.pages.system.acl_002dgroup_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(acl_002dgroup_jsp.java:368)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.pages.system.acl_002dgroup_jsp._jspService(acl_002dgroup_jsp.java:317)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:361)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.
```

Comment: You say that "In my sample application this worked perfect" however at ie doesn't. What's your exact problem, it doesn't work with ie but work with other browsers?

Comment: We need to see the exact code snippet that is failing. In your code snippet, your var is "menu", not "parameters", which is what it looks like the var is in the failure case. It would also help to see exactly how you are trying to do the checkbox.

Comment: I see you recently edited your answer to include an example of how you are using a checkbox... if you noticed the example I provided of what not to do (because it won't work) is functionally identical to what you said you are trying to do. You are trying to use the value attribute where you should be using the fieldValue attribute. the value attribute must resolve to a boolean.

Comment: <s:iterator value="menuGroup" var="menuLst">
    <s:checkbox fieldValue="%{#menuLst.name}" value="true"></s:checkbox>
   </s:iterator>

Comment: this code also gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more straight forward to write:

```
<s:iterator value="menuGroup">
  <s:textfield value="name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Now because there is no other information provided, did you write the equivalent (which is wrong btw):

```
<s:iterator value="menuGroup">
  <s:checkbox value="name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Because you can name and label a checkbox with a string but the value has to be a boolean, as that refers to the check box status, not to be confused with the fieldValue attribute which is equivalent to the html checkbox parameter "value". See: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/checkbox.html

If you find the tags a hindrance just write the checkbox as html http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: Thank you for you guide finally <s:checkbox value="aBoolean" fieldValue="true" label="%{#menu.name}"
     name="%{#menu.name}"></s:checkbox> this works perfect